# How do I make a Parent-Child association where deleting the child will delete the parent, but not vice versa

Tags: sql, sqlite, sequelize.js

I am currently trying to make two create two tables that have a 1:M association. What I'm trying to achieve is this:

`Parent deleted? -> Set foreign key in Child to null
Child deleted? -> Delete parent`

I've been trying this for quite some time and am not sure if this is actually possible. These are my create table queries (generated by [sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/), a sql node.js module)

Parent table:
`` CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Sets` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, `appId` INTEGER NOT NULL, `cardAmount` INTEGER NOT NULL, `foil` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL, `reserved` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL); ``

Child table:
`` CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Cards` (`assetId` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, `appId` INTEGER NOT NULL, `foil` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL, `reserved` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL, `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `setId` INTEGER REFERENCES `Sets` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE); ``

I'm not really sure what to change about them to make it work like I want it to, since the parent table doesn't have a foreign key I dont think its possible to add an ON DELETE. Help is appreciated!!

EDIT: The dialect that im using is SQLite

Comment: Wait...if you delete the _child_, the parent gets deleted?  I might suggest that you reverse the labels of parent and child if this is really the case.

Comment: This is indeed the case, and I have thought about doing that before but it just doesn't seem rational to me. A set consists of 5 to 15 cards, so to me it would only seem logical that the set would be the parent. But I'm quite OCD when it comes to coding stuff so I'll just do it anyway if there isn't another solution. Thanks!

Comment: What if there is more than one child? Do you realize that the final ("terminal") child in the hierarchy has no children at all?

Comment: @joop I'm not quite sure what you mean, a record in Sets has multiple children in Cards, that's all

Comment: So you want to disallow empty sets? -> only delete the parent set record when the *last* child member record is removed. In most SQL implementation this will need a trigger + some  procedural code. (BTW: disallowing empty sets is probably a bad model BTW2: I got the feeling the members should be unique within sets, too...)

Comment: I don't want to disallow empty sets, I want to delete the set when one of the cards in the set is deleted, because the set always has to have an exact amount of cards. But now that I'm thinking about it this wouldn't even be needed. I'm not going to directly delete cards that are in sets, thats only going to be done through the set record, so all I would have to do is make sure that all cards are deleted when their parent set is deleted, so all I would need is ON DELETE CASCADE. I'm sorry for wasting your time, my brain bugged out. Thank you for trying to help though!

Answer (score 0):

We can add `ON DELETE` option during assocation.

```
Parent.hasOne(models.Child, {
    onDelete: 'set null'
});
```

This will set null to the `foreignKey` in Child model. But to delete parent when child is deleted, try deleting Parent using hooks `beforeDestroy` or `afterDestroy` in Child model.